# Create pdf with subset of slides

Tags: beamer, xetex, knitr

I use knitr and RStudio with XeLaTeX to create a presentation with many slides. But sometimes not all of the slides should appear in the final pdf. Is it possible to have a variable that I change depending on if all slides should be included or not?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

#Here I would like to set parameter allslides=FALSE so that the tomato-slide "disappears" from pdf

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{A Slide about Apples}
Bla bla
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{A Slide about Tomatoes}
Bla bla
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{A Slide about Bananas}
Bla bla
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The slides that should disappear have content that the receiver of the pdf should not get.

I tried using \includeonlyframes but couldn't get it to work (all slides disappeared).

Comment: You could try the `ifthen` package and define a new environment that does nothing whenever you want all slides and is `\comment` when you want to exclude some. You just put this environment around the slides in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the job, however gives an error about an `extra }` I can't get rid of. If anyone could fix it I'd be happy to adjust the example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{tomatoes}
\setboolean{tomatoes}{true} 


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{A Slide about Apples}
Bla bla
\end{frame}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{tomatoes}}{
\begin{frame}[fragile]{A Slide about Tomatoes}
Bla bla
\end{frame}
}{}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{A Slide about Bananas}
Bla bla
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `environ` package to define a conditional frame environment that gobbles its contents. For example, the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{environ}

\newenvironment{tomatoframe}{\begin{frame}}{\end{frame}}
%\NewEnviron{tomatoframe}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A Slide about Apples}
Bla bla
\end{frame}

\begin{tomatoframe}{A Slide about Tomatoes}
Bla bla
\end{tomatoframe}

\begin{frame}{A Slide about Bananas}
Bla bla
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

To get a pdf where the tomato frame is dropped, uncomment the `NewEnviron` line and comment the `newenvironment` line.